# How to toggle font awesome icon in pure javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Below is my html and js codes for enabling and disabling the text box on button click. It's working perfectly, but now I need to keep fontawesome icons for button on edit or save.

HTML

```
<form name="qtyEdit">
    <input type ="text" id ="textBox1" value="7" readonly>
    <input type="button" id="qtyBtnEdit" onClick="enableDisable()" value="Edit">
</form>
```

JS

```
function enableDisable() {
    var form = document.qtyEdit;
    if(form.qtyBtnEdit.value=="Edit"){
        form.textBox1.readOnly = false;
        form.qtyBtnEdit.value="Save"
    }
    else{
        form.textBox1.readOnly = true;
        form.qtyBtnEdit.value="Edit"
    }
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Ok, first of all welcome. 2nd of all, please set up a working example on a website like JSfiddle.net. 3rd of all: please make your question more clear, I tried salvaging it with an edit, but it still makes no sense to me.

Comment: Change class of font-awesome icon on edit and save .

Comment: Hi Tq for your replay @Rvervuurt here is the working example https://jsfiddle.net/9czp3151/1/

Comment: You demo has nothing to do with Font Awesome It's not clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: So, you want to display an icon instead of the button? And have that button change icon when pressed?

Comment: yes thats what am expecting @Rvervuurt

Comment: @vinay Add an `<i class="fa fa-camera-retro"></i>` ( with the font-awesome classes you want ) inside your button( Ya `make the input tag as a button tag` ). Now when you are changing the text, `change the font-awesome class` of <i> tag there itself. Bingo !!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the input a button so that you can add content inside:

```
<input type="button" id="qtyBtnEdit" onClick="enableDisable()" value="Edit">
```

becomes

```
<button type="button" id="qtyBtnEdit" onClick="enableDisable()">Edit</button>
```

add the fa icon:

```
<button type="button" id="qtyBtnEdit" onClick="enableDisable()"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-pencil'></i>Edit</button>
```

to toggle this between edit/save (I've used jquery as the question was tagged jquery):

```
function enableDisable() {
    if ($("#qtyBtnEdit i").hasClass("fa-pencil")) {
        // Is edit, so change
        $("#qtyBtnEdit").text("Save");
    }
    else {
        // Back to edit
        $("#qtyBtnEdit").text("Edit");
    }
    $("#qtyBtnEdit i").toggleClass("fa-pencil fa-floppy-io")
}
```

---

If you want just an icon and no text, remove the text from the button and code:

```
<button type="button" id="qtyBtnEdit" onClick="enableDisable()"><i class='fa fa-fw fa-pencil'></i></button>
```

and

```
function enableDisable() {
    $("#qtyBtnEdit i").toggleClass("fa-pencil fa-floppy-io")
}
```

Comment: Thank Q So much for the detailed explantaion @freedomn-m

Answer (score 2):

Try the `classList.toggle` function:

```js
function enableDisable() {
  var form = document.qtyEdit;
  var icon = document.getElementById("icon");
  if(form.qtyBtnEdit.value=="Edit"){
    form.textBox1.readOnly = false;
    form.qtyBtnEdit.value="Save";
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-pencil');
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-floppy-o');
  }
  else{
    form.textBox1.readOnly = true;
    form.qtyBtnEdit.value="Edit";
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-floppy-o');
    icon.classList.toggle('fa-pencil');
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css">
<form name="qtyEdit">
  <input type ="text" id ="textBox1" value="7" readonly>
  <input type="button" id="qtyBtnEdit" onClick="enableDisable()" value="Edit">
  <i id="icon" class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
</form>
```